# How to Hide a DIV if Variable is Null

Tags: html, css, variables, display

I have a div and a variable inside it, and would like to hide the div if the variable is empty. Any clues? For example:

```
<div class='h-box'>
<h1>text<h1/>
<p><?php echo regular_he(); ?><p/>
</div>
```

Comment: what this regular_he() ?, What it returns

Comment: @ManiruzzamanAkash That is the variable (or is this called array? I'm new to this). I have a few of them. Some of them contain text, and some have a link to an audio file.

Answer (score 2):

You can check variable by only if that is empty or null

```
if($var == "" && $var == NULL){
  // Do your work
}
```

And For Array,

```
if(!empty($array_name)){
  // Do your work
}
```

Full Example,

```
<?php
    $name = "Akash";
    $test_array = [];
    function regular_he(){
         return "Something";
    }
?>
 <!-- For Variable -->
<?php if($name != "" && $name != NULL): ?>
    <div class='h-box'>
        <h1>text<h1/>
        <p><?php echo regular_he(); ?><p/>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>


<!-- For Array -->
<?php if(!empty($test_array)): ?>
    <div class='h-box'>
        <h1>text<h1/>
        <p><?php echo regular_he(); ?><p/>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is empty with PHP `is_empty` function:

```
<?php if(is_empty($var_to_check)): ?>
  <div class='h-box'>
    <h1>text<h1/>
    <p><?php echo regular_he(); ?><p/>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php