# How is this IF statement working?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have the following code which is working, but I don't understand why it works.
It is an IF statement, and what happens is if `$VAR` has a value it displays the DIV, but if it doesn't, it wont display the `DIV`. I am new to programming, and I would think that the way I have the code, the `DIV` should not show up if $VAR has a value. Please help me understand. Thanks!

```
<?php
    if (!empty($VAR)) { ?>
    <div class='543'>
        <H1>Complete.</h1>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Say, didn't you post something similar not so long ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489061/how-to-hide-a-div-if-variable-is-null - You have some answers in there that resemble the ones given for your post here. What's not working for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Hide a DIV if Variable is Null
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489061/how-to-hide-a-div-if-variable-is-null)

Comment: It was not meant to be a duplicate. I am just asking how this code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(!empty($VAR))`

When you use an `!` followed by [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), then it means "if $VAR is not empty".  That's why your div is showing up when there is a value for VAR.

Comment: So `!` means not?

Comment: The OP's post is a repost of [How to Hide a DIV if Variable is Null
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489061/how-to-hide-a-div-if-variable-is-null).

Comment: Yes, the ! means "not"